# How can I parse a JSON-formatted string into Tree Int

Tags: haskell, tree

I have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Tree

main :: IO ()
main = print $ decode "[1,[2,[]]]" :: Maybe (Tree Int)
```

But the output is "Nothing" in the console. How can I parse JSON data into `Tree String`, `Tree Int` types ? As far as I know, `Tree v` has a `fromJSON` instance as long as `v` has a `fromJSON` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not very familiar with how Aeson defines these instances, so I went looking on Hackage. In the module where this instance is defined, [`Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.1.1.0/docs/src/Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON.html), I see this code:

```
instance ToJSON1 Tree.Tree where
    liftToJSON t tol = go
      where
        go (Tree.Node root branches) =
            liftToJSON2 t tol to' tol' (root, branches)

        to' = liftToJSON go (listValue go)
        tol' = liftToJSONList go (listValue go)

    liftToEncoding t tol = go
      where
        go (Tree.Node root branches) =
            liftToEncoding2 t tol to' tol' (root, branches)

        to' = liftToEncoding go (listEncoding go)
        tol' = liftToEncodingList go (listEncoding go)

instance (ToJSON v) => ToJSON (Tree.Tree v) where
    toJSON = toJSON1
    toEncoding = toEncoding1
```

The call to `liftToJSON2` here, and reading `instance ToJSON2 (,)` and `instance ToJSON1 []`, tells me that a `Node` is represented as an array of two elements, where the former is the encoding of the root value, and the latter is the encoding of the branches. Since this is a list, it’s also encoded as an array.

So your example case `[1,[2,[]]]` is close, but you’re missing one level of nesting—since `Tree 1 [Tree 2 []]` is encoded via `(1, [(2, [])])`, I infer that it needs to be `[1,[[2,[]]]]`. This is probably documented somewhere, but I can’t easily find it.

Comment: Really appreciate this. I can't thank you enough.